# How to convert byte array to image file?

Tags: c#, arrays, type-conversion

I have browsed and uploaded a png/jpg file in my MVC web app.
I have stored this file as byte[] in my database.
Now I want to read and convert the byte[] to original file.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

1. Create a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) passing the array in the constructor.
2. Read the image from the stream using [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx).
3. Call [theImg.Save("theimage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx).

Remember to reference System.Drawing.Imaging and use a **using** block for the stream.

Comment: The Image roundtrip makes no sense if the byte array already contains a valid image. Just ues `File.WriteAllBytes()` or whatever to directly write the byte array's contents to a file.

Answer (score 27):

Create a memory stream from the byte[] array in your database and then use Image.FromStream.

```
byte[] image = GetImageFromDatabase();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
Image i = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Answer (score 6):

May you have trouble with the mentioned solutions on DotNet Core 3.0 or higher

so my solution is:

```
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(yourByteArray)) {
   using(var fs = new FileStream("savePath", FileMode.Create)) {
      ms.WriteTo(fs);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Or just use this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
```

[File.WriteAllBytes(String, Byte[]) Method (System.IO) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=net-5.0)