# How to generate .pkpass files in C# to add to my e-wallet?

Tags: c#

I have an app written in C# that generates cards (similar to our personal id). Now, i wanted to add that card to an e-wallet. I searched through the web and found that to do that i needed to create a .pkpass file and then i could upload this file to my e-wallet. First of all, is this the only way to add my card to my e-wallet?
Also, i understood that i needed certificates. I took a peek at Passbook Generator and it is said that i need a full Apple developer account (which i don't have) to download one of the certificates. So, i'm struggling a bit to understand what i really need to accomplish what i want.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Rafael Valente

Answer (score 0):

the following worked for me

```
DirectoryInfo location = new DirectoryInfo(SourceLocation);
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(location.FullName);
XmlDocument PkPassFile = new XmlDocument();
MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
PkPassFile.Load(memstream);
string FullFileName = DestinationFolder+ @"\" + file.Name + ".pkpass";
rdlFile.Save(FullFileName);
```

basically you read the file into a byte[],

take that and paste it into memorystream,

add that to a xmldocument and save the conent of the xmlfile as a .pkpass file

RESULT
[image]

Comment: Please do note i do not have a way to test the conent of the files, but i did give it my best shot

Comment: Thank you for your response. If i understand your code, you get the "location" in the file system of the file you want to convert to .pkpass, then you convert it to byte[], instance the xml and the memory stream, load the xml with the memory stream and save it to file system. Is that it?

Comment: @RafaelValente yes...if you have multiple files, you might want to use a foreach..but yea, that summed it up perfectly

Comment: i'll try it in my code and give feedback. Thank you mate.

Comment: the file i want to convert has to be of some specific type? I'm trying to read a .png. This is the code i'm using:

Comment: String sourceLocation = "//fileshare.adse.interno/projs/pararede/EBS-04-00488/1_1_20170224_000017426.PNG";

DirectoryInfo location = new DirectoryInfo(sourceLocation);
            
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(location.FullName);
           
XmlDocument PkPassFile = new XmlDocument();
            
MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            
PkPassFile.Load(memstream);
            
string FullFileName = "//fileshare.adse.interno/projs/pararede/EBS-04-00488/test.pkpass";
            
PkPassFile.Save(FullFileName);

Comment: So, i'm using hardcoded strings just to try it our and i'm presented to the error: "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1". Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: well the error is exactly what it says, the data is invalid....The file is a .png and i believe images cant be converted to xml... so the error comes in at the xmldocument...best way would be to find another object you can save the byte[] in and then save from that ;)

Comment: this one will solve your problem..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102005/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-image-file

Comment: which type of file you used? I can use a .pdf also.

Comment: i used .Rdl files (Report files)...no matter what type i used,all you should be looking for is which object you will use to save your memorystream in :) and then save from that file to a .pkpass

Comment: So, what you are saying is that i have to find another object apart from the XmlDocument class?

Comment: I was successfull in generating the .pkpass but now when i try to upload the file to my e-wallet it says it's not a pkpass format. Have you tested uplodading your files to na e-wallet?

Comment: As said in this link https://www.file-extensions.org/pkpass-file-extension
a pkpass file is a zip file....
so instead of converting a bunch of files into pkpassfiles...find the related files, zip them up and convert the zip file to a pkpass file

Comment: i have no experience working with pk pass and have no way to test it, so any information you pass on is what i work with.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you @Bernard

Comment: @RafaelValente Hope you find the fix ;), do you have the zip files ?

Comment: No. I need to create the images, .json and manifest. But first i need to get the certificates from Apple Developer website. So i got plenty of things to achieve before getting the .zip.

Comment: @RafaelValente well, i tried, have a nice day though